# Add a text field within the interactive grid. ORACLE APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Hello community Is it possible that the interactive grid in the region where the search engine and its buttons can be added can be added a text field with option display only?

I have searched in different blogs and I have no results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to add a read-only text input box to an interactive report. [See this page for an example](https://www.talkapex.com/2009/09/updateable-interactive-report-for-apex/) of how to do it. The basic idea is to create a column like this:

```
select apex_item.text(1, my_source_column, 'disabled') as textbox,
   other_columns, ...
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think not; unlike `Interactive Report`'s **region button**, which can be set to be displayed *Right of interactive report search bar*, on an `Interactive Grid` page there's no such option (not for buttons, and especially not for text items).

Therefore, I'd say that you'd have to choose some other position for that item.